# I exported some WSL2 commands to Win10 using Import-WslCommand - Including nano. How do I get syntax highlighting working (Esp. for Pwsh)?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, wsl-2, nano

I added:

`Import-WslCommand "apt", "cat", "awk", "nano", "find", "grep", "head", "less", "ls", "man", "sed", "seq", "ssh", "sudo", "tail", "touch"`

To my PowerShell 7 profile. Things are working great - I love the Interoperability.

But what I can't figure out is how to get nano (and soon Neovim when I import it) to properly syntax highlight my code. I do a lot of PowerShell coding, and there is absolutely no highlighting for that in nano.

Is there a way to enable it? Something I can do?

Should I un-import Nano, and then install it on Windows? I found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1493801/how-to-install-the-nano-cli-editor-on-windows-10) and now I'm wondering if I should go that route.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much.